# Pattern in match in mapping in autocmd

Tags: key-bindings, regular-expression, autocmd

Working on a more lightweight vim-endwise replacement (endwise breaks `imap <expr> <CR>` mappings).

In the following text:

```
def name<-cursor here
```

it adds a newline and another line with an `end`:

```
def name
  <-cursor here
end
```

This mapping does the job:

```
autocmd FileType ruby inoremap <buffer> <expr> <CR> match(getline('.'), 'def') >= 0 ? '<CR><CR>end<Esc>-cc' : '<CR>'
```

However, I'd like to extend this to also understand `if`, `case` and `do`, but the following does not work:

```
autocmd FileType ruby inoremap <buffer> <expr> <CR> match(getline('.'), 'def\|if\|case\|do') >= 0 ? '<CR><CR>end<Esc>-cc' : '<CR>'
```

Even though `match("  case abc", 'def\|if\|case\|do') >= 0` returns 1 (e.g. true).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Extracting to a function does not make things easier: `'\<CR>'` returns text, not a newline, an unescaped `'<CR>'` errors out, even though `match` seems to work properly.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and put that into a normal ftplugin and simply call a function for that filetype. Then you don't have to worry about escaping all possible metachars and even better 2 days from today, you still understand what you are doing ;)

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt moved everything to a ftplugin, but still have to double escape `|`

Comment: @philpirozhkov There is another advice in Christian's comment: **define a function**. This way your regex will be simplified, and much easier to maintain.

Comment: @LucHermitte See above, in a function output needs to be escaped, e.g. `'<CR>'` does not work, nor `'\<CR>'` does, [I've seen people](https://github.com/search?p=2&q=expr+pumvisible&ref=searchresults&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) use `""<CR'` and `'\<lt>CR>'`, but none of them worked in a function. I'm pretty satisfied with my current solution, will dig deeper when I decide I need to add a closing curly brace when I open one and press CR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIRC, it's related to the *bar* character in command lines. You need to escape the bar twice, e.g.:

```
" ftplugin/ruby/myshortcuts.vim 
inoremap <buffer> <expr> <CR> match(getline('.'), 'if\\|def\\|case\\|do') >= 0 ? '<CR><CR>end<Esc>-cc' : '<CR>
```

BTW, you should make sure this is exactly `def` (and not `define`), that you aren't in string, nor comments.

Comment: alternatively, you can use `<bar>`, in place of `|`, i.e. `'def\<bar>if\<bar>case\<bar>do'` worlks

Comment: `autocmd FileType ruby inoremap <expr> <CR> match(getline('.'), 'if\\|def\\|case\\|do') >= 0 ? '<CR><CR>end<Esc>-cc' : '<CR>` worked as expected, thanks!

Comment: @nobe4 it wouldn't have been enough. A backslash is required when there is no magic around (`:h /\v`)

Comment: @LucHermitte, Yup, a `\<bar>` then ? (that's what I've put in the example)

Comment: @nobe4 Oops. Sorry I've missed the backslash in the example.

Comment: Is `<buffer>` still required if I put this into ftplugin?

Comment: @philpirozhkov. Always. Mappings that make sense only in a restrictive list of filetypes/buffers shall always be declared with `<buffer>`. Otherwise the next time you open a buffer with a different filetype, the mapping will be defined and could be triggered. Which is not what we want.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use `<bar>` instead of `|`:

```
autocmd FileType ruby inoremap <buffer> <expr> <CR> match(getline('.'), 'def\<bar>if\<bar>case\<bar>do') >= 0 ? '<CR><CR>end<Esc>-cc' : '<CR>'
```

see: `:h <bar>`